# How can I content-partner and can-read-video-streams roles from Dailymotion?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I try to retrieve an HLS stream URL of my videos on Dailymotion, calling /video/ API with stream_hls_url value in the fields parameter. But I get a 403 error with the following message:

> Unsufficient roles for the 'fields' parameter of 'GET /video/<id>' with 'stream_hls_url' value, roles required: content-partner, can-read-video-streams

How could I obtain these roles, given that I'm a Dailymotion partner?

Answer (score 0):

You should either contact your Dailymotion content manager if you have one, or get in touch with us by writing your request to https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en/requests/new

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming to this question with a similar response from an API request; please check the fields you're requesting within your request against those listed in the [Dailymotion API Data API Reference](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-fields).

Often this "403" response, seemingly due to "Unsufficient Roles" (yes that's a typo), is *actually* down to requesting a field that no longer exists within the defined reference (linked above). This happens more than it should, with little or no notice to the end user - as demonstrated here.

I hope this helps :)